# Is there an audio player with waveform seekbar?

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, audio, mediaplayer, waveform

I'm looking for a player with seekbar that displays the waveform of the playing song, like http://foobar2000.org + http://foobar2000.org/components/view/foo_wave_seekbar

Specifically, a seekBar is an extension of ProgressBar that adds a draggable thumb and also provides a waveform preview of track in the background of the bar's on-screen area.

[image]

Comment: Would you settle for audio editing software? This sort of view is generally the realm of editors, not playback-only software.

Comment: @diimdeep I'm not sure what you mean by seekbar. Could you explain this, please?

Comment: seekBar is an extension of ProgressBar that adds a draggable thumb. waveform seekbar also provides waveform preview of track in background.

Comment: @diimdeep Thanks! BTW: I found this very detailed description @ [wiki.hydrogenaudio.org](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Components/Waveform_Seekbar_(foo_wave_seekbar)).

Comment: This site covers OS X and iOS. Is it OS X you're focused on here?

Comment: A nice web app that provides this functionality is http://soundcloud.com/ it fits all the criteria in your question and is cross-platform and hosted storage.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

http://nulloy.com is a player that runs not only on OS X but also Linux and Windows. I'm the developer of it.

[image]

Comment: See http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior.  Re *"you must disclose your affiliation in your answers."*

Comment: Please forgive my bad manners, never used stackexchange before.

Comment: Nulloy is great, very quick and light weight.

Comment: Searching for an answer to this as well.. Nulloy **does not** support the Mac .m4v suffix, and this far, I've seen no .mp4 that does't simply present an error in the application.

Comment: Doesn't work for me. getting `Error: Internal data flow error.` on load and then on playback. (Using latest version 0.8.2.)

Comment: @FabienSnauwaert I didn't find another way to contact you, but would you please make a [bug report](https://github.com/nulloy/nulloy/issues)?

Answer (score 7):

Its more of an audio *editor* than a *player*, so might not be exactly what you want, but [Fission](http://rogueamoeba.com/fission/) from Rogue Amoeba is an excellent tool that displays the waveform of the loaded audio file. You can zoom in and out of portions of the audio and drag the play point to wherever you wish.

[image]

Comment: I'm looking for player, not editor, but thanks anyway

Answer (score 6):

[Capo](http://supermegaultragroovy.com/products/Capo/)

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

[GarageBand](http://www.apple.com/ilife/garageband/)

[SoundCloud](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/soundcloud/id412754595?mt=12) app for Mac OS X

These programs all have different purposes. Some are commercial and some are free. Each of them will do what you want.

Comment: Audacity is ok.

Answer (score 6):

This is more of a workaround, but you can open it with the standard QuickTime player and "trim", and it brings up the waveform of the track. 
Menu Edit > Trim (<kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>)

[image]

Comment: nice! thanks for reminding me of a way to do this without getting a new app.

Answer (score 5):

## [VirtualDJ Home Version](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/virtualdj-home/id417934534?mt=12) (free)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

## [Transitions Player](http://itunes.apple.com/ru/app/transitions-player/id460127911?mt=12) (free)

[image]

Comment: This claims to not be available in my country. Is it even available anywhere now? This is 8 years old after all!

Answer (score 2):

## [MIXXX](http://www.mixxx.org/) (open source)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

An option that would work and is free is [Praat](http://www.fon.hum.uva.nl/praat/download_mac.html). It's designed for linguists and terrible in terms of UI, but it does include a wave form and the possibility to select part of it for playback.

[image: Praat audio sound wave]

(Use Tab to play back.)

Answer (score 0):

i have the same question and find this, but is only for windows (my OS).Mi don't know if there is a Mac version or if you can use an emulator
http://audiops.codeplex.com/

[image]

Answer (score -2):

waveform seekbar comes as default for AIMP player, also can download more skins.  In screenshot, I'm using Bliss skin.

[AIMP for windows](https://www.aimp.ru/)

[image]

Comment: The asker was looking for a macOS solution